# (Crowdsourced) Dataset with label/annotation metadata like duration/quality

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, deep-learning, crowdsourcing

I'm looking for a research project for datasets (the more the better), potentially crowdsourced, which go beyond basic feature vectors + labels, and include additionally some metadata about the labels. Specifically I'd like the annotation time, or some other cost metric, and if the dataset was crowdsourced, the individual labels per annotator. On top, some measure of the quality of the labels by different annotators would be helpful as well. The Dataset domain is not relevant.

So far I could only find [this](https://bmcresnotes.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13104-019-4858-z) dataset.